# How to edit/create/delete relations / references [react-admin]

Tags: react-admin

Given the demo category edit page as a reference
https://marmelab.com/react-admin-demo/#/categories/0

Is there a built-in way/guidelines to add/remove products from the category? i can't find any reference about in in the docs/example

Answer (score 0):

No man, you should do it by yourself according your needs. 
You can only create separate list with actions as shown in tutorial and edit it outside of category itself, as standalone table. 
If u want to edit list of products which only belongs to concrete category, you should create your own component.
You may be need something like that example: https://codesandbox.io/s/rm4jy6n68o